# Android Studio Build Failed Incorrect value for field 'signature'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I'm getting the following error when attempting to run an app or build my project in android studio

`Incorrect value for field 'Signature': value is 1163874895 but 67324752 expected.`

Initially I got this when adding the kotlin-android-extensions line to my apps build.gradle

```
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Since then I've tried removing it, cleaning/rebuilding, invalidating the cache, deleting the project and recreating, and uninstalling android studio and user settings. Now I can't even create a new project with only an empty activity and build it. I'm new to android, kotlin, and gradle and not really sure what else to check.

Comment: Redownload android sdk.

Comment: Tried redownloading but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by deleting the folders

- C:\Users<username>.android
- C:\Users<username>.gradle